# ASP.net MVC - ViewModel object and Session variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, viewmodel

Say I have the following situation:

- A paginated View displays a list of contacts with the following route: Contacts/Index/Page/2.
- The View gets its paginated data ViewModel object.
- The View also gets its filter properties from the ViewModel, like the Contact Category.

I would like to store the page number and the filter properties somewhere in such a way that when the user returns to Contacts/Index page, the same page number and filters are applied.

Is it good practice to store these properties within a Session variable? 
Should the ViewModel be handling these Session variables?

Is there another way to tackle this type of situation?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to have the same filters/page after you have returned from another page back, then you must use session, there is no other better way

Comment: It looks like the user who asked this question is no longer a member of the site.

Comment: This is how I had to accomplish the same thing.  User performs a search, then edits one of the items from the search, possibly a sequence of multiple pages, and in the end must be returned the original search results.  Session variable for the win.